# Open source HTML editor with design view

Tags: html-editor

Looking out for open source HTML editors with design view like Adobe Dreamweaver or Microsoft Expression Web .

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia is always useful for this kind of researches: [Comparison of HTML editors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_HTML_editors)

OpenBEXI, Quanta, Kompozer, Amaya and SeaMonkey could fit your need.

Answer (score 0):

I've used CoffeeCup's free html editor on occasion and found it's pretty good. Not open source though.

http://www.coffeecup.com/free-editor/

Comment: Checking coffee Cup now, I mean open source or free both will do :D